# HTML save links to files and use them to link later

Tags: javascript, html, linux

The last person before me at my work place was quite good and has been working alone for 4 years on the website. He quit and now I am taking his place.

Yesteday, I have executed a "git fetch --all" on the Linux server and somehow messed something up, we have 2 websites that are in a folder and next to their folders are some global JavaScripts, the first website is ok, working fine but the second is not working and is not referencing correctly?

The tree looks something like this:

```
{
    + Site1
      - httpsdocs
          - files (src="www.site1.com/javascripts/shared/scripts.js"> )
      - httpdocs
          - files (src="www.site1.com/javascripts/shared/scripts.js"> )
      - javascripts
           - shared ( This is literally a file with no extension that has in it "../../shared" )


    + Site2
      - httpsdocs
          - files (src="www.site2.com/javascripts/shared/scripts.js"> )
      - httpdocs
          - files (src="www.site2.com/javascripts/shared/scripts.js" )
      - javascripts
           - shared ( This is literally a file with no extension that has in it "../../shared" )

    + Shared
        + jScript File
        + Css File
}
```

Somehow he managed to do something like:

```
<script src="www.website.com/javascripts/TEXTFILE/script.js" ></script>
```

How did he manage to do that? I cannot get it to work for the hell of it, I have checked the `.htaccess` and don't seem to find anything in it? Does anyone have any idea? Getting pretty desperate here as the guy doesn't return calls anymore.

I am sorry if the question has been asked before or it was in plain sight, but I have been Googling it since yesteday and the website is basically broken and I have tried every single combination of tags to look for answers but can't seem to find any... help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out how the respective person managed to do that, we are running on linux servers (ofc) and linux has something called [SymbolicLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) Hopefully this will help others with the probleme since no one was able to answering it.